# How to generate a function of two variables without using any loop?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

Suppose I have a function y(t,x) = exp(-t)*sin(x)

In Matlab, I define

```
t = [0: 0.5: 5];
x = [0: 0.1: 10*2*pi];
y = zeros(length(t), length(x)); % empty matrix init
```

Now, how do I define matrix y **without using any loop**, such that each element y(i,j) contains the value of desired function y at `(t(i), x(j))`? Below is how I did it using a for loop.

```
for i = 1:length(t)
    y(i,:) =  exp(-t(i)) .* sin(x);
end
```

Comment: Not sure you can - is the loop taking to long to run, or why do you want to?

Comment: The loop is not a problem here in this simple example. But I want to learn the way to do it without loop for really large vectors!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your input  vectors `x` is `1xN` and `t` is `1xM`, output matrix `y` is `MxN`. To vectorize the code both `x` and `t` must have the same dimension as `y`.

```
[x_,t_] = meshgrid(x,t);
y_ =  exp(-t_) .* sin(x_);
```

Your example is a simple 2D case. Function `meshgrid()` works also 3D. Sometimes you can not avoid the loop, in such cases, when your loop can go either 1:N or 1:M, choose the shortest one. Another function I use to prepare vector for vectorized equation (vector x matrix multiplication) is `diag()`.

Answer (score 6):

there is no need for `meshgrid`; simply use:

```
y = exp(-t(:)) * sin(x(:)');    %multiplies a column vector times a row vector.
```

Answer (score 2):

Those might be helpful:
http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html

http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/digest/sept00/meshgrid.html

Good Luck.